# how to send user on a page after clicking on an ad

Tags: php, wordpress, web

I'm obviously not talking about an Adsense program :).

I'm wondering what's the better approach to display a page after the user clicked on my website Ad on a wordpress blog.

Comment: I guess I wasn't explicit enough, sorry everyone.

I'd like to have a sort of pay article :
to access it, you have to click on an advert first;
So basically when you click on the advert you'll be redirected to the advert page, AND it opens the article too.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if that is what youre looking for but you need to use a normal link

```
<a href="https://www.example.com" target="_blank"></a>
```

in between the a and /a you need to post your image or whatever your ad is.
So basicly now your ad is a link, redirecting to example.com in an additional browser tab.

an other way is to use the header function. you would need to add aditional code to that.

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
exit();
?>
```

Hope i could help you

KB

Answer (score 0):

Yes you put link where you want to redirect  for ex.

click